# Rails will_paginate and paging newest records in ASC order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-order-by, will-paginate

How to paginate posts with **will_paginate**, so that first page shows **10 latest posts in ASC order**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your post model right at the top:

```
cattr_reader :per_page
@@per_page = 10
default_scope :order => 'created_at DESC'
```

Comment: but this is going to display 10 latest posts, not 10 latest in ASC order (the way chat works)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this code should do the job in your controller.

```
def index
 @posts = Post.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10, :order => 'created_at ASC'
end
```